# Test case history in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible to see history of individual test case results in Jenkins? Basically, I want to know at what revisions a particular test case failed. There must be plug-in for that but I can't find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the relevant project, click on **Latest test result**, then drill down to the test of interest, then click **History**.

Comment: I don't see a **Latest test result** option. Any chance you have a plugin that I don't have?

Comment: @Milad: I have a ton of plugins installed, but this *should* be vanilla Jenkins behaviour.  To be fair, I'm running an old version (1.559), so it's possible the UI has changed...

Comment: I think I've found it. Thank you very much. I guess what I'm looking for is an easier way to access this. I have to go deep in a particular build in order to access this.

Comment: @Milad: You mean it's a lot of clicks?  Note that you can just bookmark the URL, though!  (Note also that Jenkins URLs follow a consistent structure...)

Comment: True. I just found this plugin: http://junitth.sourceforge.net Looks like what I'm looking for